# Why was this low activity question "protected"?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113160/how-can-i-make-you-tube-full-screen-on-my-ipad-when-using-safari) a while ago and it has garnered no upvotes and a single upvoted answer.  The answer is correct and useful so I accepted it.

Today I happened back onto this question and see that it was "protected" to prevent answers by users with < 10 rep.  My understanding of the use of "protection" is to prevent pile-on when questions go viral.

Why would such a low activity question get protected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question has attracted a bunch of "me too" answers which have been deleted (and which you can't see). The software behind AskDifferent automatically sets a topic to "protected" if the ratio between deleted and non-deleted questions gets too high.

I've unprotected it again for the moment, if it keeps attracting "me too" answers it will get procted again automatically.

Comment: What is a "me too" answer? a-I have the same problem, or b-too many similar proposed solutions. I gave what I thought was a possible solution this morning (early morning CET) and now all traces have vanished. There were no visible previous answers so if "me too" == option b above there was no way of knowing. This is confusing.

Comment: "me too" is "I have the same problem". Your answer still seems to be around: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125479/im-locked-out-of-machine-as-will-not-accept-password-as-i-shut-down-while-using/125522#125522